# PHP - If else condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to create an if-else condition in PHP between 2 variables in an array.

PHP Code:

```
   $todaysData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

    $tomorrowData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

    //HTML TABLE WHERE I WANT TO PRINT THE RESULTS
    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-1">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 118px;">
            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><?php echo $todaysData['Fajr Begins']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-2">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 118px;">
            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-3-base u-table-cell-2"><?php echo $todaysData['Fajr Jamaat']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-3">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 72px;">
            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-2-base u-table-cell-3"><?php echo $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

The condition:
If $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] > $todaysData['Fajr Jamat'] then echo $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] else echo "-"

I want to see this condition value in the html table data : `<td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-2-base u-table-cell-3"><?php echo $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']; ?></td>`

Comment: jsut need to use ternary condition as :  <?php echo ($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] >  $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']) ? $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] : '-'  ?>

Comment: That didnt work... I also tried the following which didnt work either :
<?php
if ($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] != $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']) {
    echo "$tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']";
} else {
    echo "-";
}
?>

Comment: what type of data it contains ? is it integer or string or date ?

Comment: varchar(255) - string but the output is a time .. for example 06:00 or 13:00
the "!=" (not equal to) should work for string no ?

Comment: Here is a snippet of my code:
// read first row with today's data
$todaysData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

// Now read second row, with tomorrow's data.
$tomorrowData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

// If condition for Changes of salah times
if ($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] != $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']) {
    echo "$tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']";
} else {
    echo "$tomorrowData["-"]";
}

{
?>

            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-2-base u-table-cell-3"><?php echo $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

Comment: if the data you getting is of date then check by : <?php echo (strtotime($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat']) > strtotime($todaysData['Fajr Jamat'])) ? $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] : '-' ?>

Comment: varchar(255) - string but the output is a time .. for example 06:00 or 13:00 the "!=" (not equal to) should work for string no ?  :-  "!==" would work better

Comment: It seems that you have the same value either $tomorrowData and $todayData because the fetch command is referring the same variable $records. Have you try to echo the two value for check if the values are correct and different?

Comment: If you use the same variable $records both to $todaysData and $tomorrowData, then both arrays will be equals, having the same values.

Comment: Nearly there!
This worked :
<?php echo ($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] == $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']) ? $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] : '-' ?></td>

I now need to put the else condition so that $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] will echo its value if its not same as $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']. I tried this but didnt work :
<?php echo ($tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] == $todaysData['Fajr Jamat']) ? $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] : '-'
else if $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamaat'] !== $todaysData['Fajr Jamat'] 
? $tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat'] : '$tomorrowData['Fajr Jamat']' ?></td>